# Using subversion on an CIFS mounted share

Tags: apache-httpd, samba, subversion, smb, sqlite

I am setting up an *ubuntu svn/apache2 server* for our production environment.
Also, it is mandatory, that the actual data is saved on a centralized location in our environment(different server, mounted via *smb4*).

Problem:

When commiting files from an *svn client* (testet on Windows and MacOSX) a revision was created and even data was uploaded. But at the end of the committing process, the svn client was throwing an error:

```
Warning: post commit FS processing had error: Couldn't open rep-cache database '/home/svn/repos/db/rep-cache.db'
```

I have created other *svn repos* which were not on an mounted *CIFS* drive without problems. this error only occurs, when the repo is on the mounted smb share.

Below, you can see my */etc/fstab* entry for the svn share and the ownership of the data

```
//10.0.1.50/virtuelle-DBs/svn-repos /home/svn/ cifs rw,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,user=USER,password=PASS 0 0
```

```
$ls -la /home/svn/repos
total 1
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 21 15:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 21 15:58 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 246 Jul 21 15:58 README.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 21 15:58 conf
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 22 09:20 db
-r-xr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   2 Jul 21 15:58 format
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 21 15:58 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data   0 Jul 21 15:58 locks
```

```
$ls -la /home/svn/repos/db
total 19
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 22 09:20 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:58 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2 Jul 22 09:20 current
-r-xr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    41 Jul 21 15:58 format
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     5 Jul 21 15:58 fs-type
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 10835 Jul 21 15:58 fsfs.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2 Jul 21 15:58 min-unpacked-rev
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:59 rep-cache.db
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     0 Jul 22 09:19 rep-cache.db-journal
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:58 revprops
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:58 revs
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     0 Jul 22 09:20 transactions
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     2 Jul 22 09:19 txn-current
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:58 txn-current-lock
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     0 Jul 22 09:20 txn-protorevs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data    74 Jul 21 15:58 uuid
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data     0 Jul 21 15:58 write-lock
```

Did I do something wrong in my fstab? because *www-data* should have all permissions which are nessessary to edit the *rep-cache.db*?
I even tried mounting the share with 0777 permissions.

Or does this, perhaps, have to do with *SQlite*?
Does svn even handle its DBs over sql? My understanding of databases is very shallow.